# MYSQL Query taking too much time for false scenarios

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query like this,

```
select o.order_id 
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.order_name = 'XL' 
AND o.order_status='SUCCESS' 
AND o.order_type='LARGE' 
ORDER by o.created_at ASC limit 1;
```

This is working fine when it has a returns a value. But it takes very long to execute for scenarios where the query has no records to return.

I have added separate index on `created_at(idx_created_at)` and `(order_name, order_status, order_type)(idx_name_status_type)` but with no improvements.

This is the query plan

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                             | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | NULL       | ref  | orders_order_status,idx_name_status_type                  | orders_order_status | 1       | const |    1 |     5.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Could you please let me know what might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using your index from your execution plan but there is a  cost of sorting.

I would add `created_at` column in the `idx_name_status_type` index, because you are doing `ORDER by o.created_at ASC limit 1` which will try to order the result set after the query filter the condition.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name_status_type 
ON orders (order_name, order_status, order_type,created_at);
```

Comment: We tried with that index as well, still it did not help.

Comment: @HindolDey How long did you update your statistics of orders?

Comment: if you have a long time didn't update that, try to use `ANALYZE TABLE orders;` then do query

Comment: I tried that as well. No luck.

Comment: @HindolDey Could you try to use `FORCE INDEX`, `SELECT o.order_id 
FROM orders o FORCE INDEX(idx_name_status_type)
WHERE o.order_name = 'XL' 
AND o.order_status='SUCCESS' 
AND o.order_type='LARGE' 
ORDER by o.created_at ASC limit 1;`

Comment: I have read that solution. But, since this query is getting deprecated, I was wondering if there's a solution besides this.

Comment: @HindolDey I saw your query plan is using orders_order_status index. But there isn't any information about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241745/discussion-between-hindol-dey-and-d-shih).